# How do you initialize NSXMLDocument with an XML string in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to acquire values from an xml string, but being new to Swift I can't figure out how to initialize the NSXMLDocument object.  I'm trying:

```
var xmlString:String = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"><results><item1><name>Something</name><price>10.99</price></item1></results>"
var xml:NSXMLDocument = NSXMLDocument(xmlString)
```

I'm getting the error "Cannot find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments".  I've tried converting the string to NSData but I end up with the same error:

```
var nsData:NSData = xmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var xml:NSXMLDocument = NSXMLDocument(nsData)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSXMLDocument doesn't contain an initializer than only takes a string as a parameter. There is [initWithXMLString:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLDocument/initWithXMLString:options:error:) though, which should solve your problem. Something like:

```
let xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"><results><item1><name>Something</name><price>10.99</price></item1></results>"
var error: NSError?
let xml = NSXMLDocument(XMLString: xmlString, options: 0, error: &error)
```